# Science practice: Where to introduce approximations?

Tags: algorithms, gradient-descent, approximation, scoring-rules, philosophical

In my work, I am using an algorithm which relies on estimates of the gradient of the log-posterior at a collection of Monte Carlo samples. Since this gradient is not available in closed form, I must introduce an approximation.

I have two spots in my algorithm where I can introduce this approximation: I could (a) either approximate the gradients from the logposterior values directly, or (b) approximate the loglikelihood gradients from the loglikelihood values and add them to the (analytically available) logprior gradients. Both approaches yield an approximation of the logposterior gradient.

**Now my question**: Which of these approaches would be preferable?

I have an inkling that it might be approach (b). Approach (a) is simpler, but also introduces an approximation error for the logprior gradients, for which an otherwise better estimate would be available. This makes it intuitively less attractive for me, but is my intuition correct? Are there any best practices for these situations?

Comment: how are you approximating the gradient from the function?

Comment: I am using a radial basis function interpolation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_interpolation